# what Inputenc should I choose in Texmaker (Win7)?

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings

I've written a *main.tex* document in Kile under Debian and I want to continue writing it in Windows where I've just installed TexMaker (I need to type and hear audio-recordigs, Windows has a better sound system). Both OS have a minimum installation of TeXLive 2013 with few additional packages. When I compile the main file, I get over a dozen errors: in Kile/Debian those were classified as *Warnings* rather than *Errors*. Almost all of them say this:

> ! Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textrightarrow not provided by
>   (textcomp) font family ppl in TS1 encoding. (textcomp) Default family
>   used instead. See the textcomp package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.

I don't know what encoding to choose or what option to put for `\usepackage[???]{inputenc}`. Clearly `ISO-8859-1` isn't working AND is turning my keyboard crazy (some keys don't corresppond to the symbols above them if Ctrl or Alt keys are also pressed). TexMaker is suggesting UTF-8. I thought adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{warn}{textcomp}` in the preamble would help compile the file...but to no avail!
Help me please, I need to expedite my work!

**MWE:**

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts, xfrac} %tutto matematica
\usepackage{outlines}    
\PassOptionsToPackage{warn}{textcomp}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
 \1 What was blah blaha and blah?
 \2[] blah blah \textrightarrow{} lorem ipsum etc.
 \end{outline}

\end{document}
```

**2nd not-so-MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label= \roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\textbf{\alph*})}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\SIrange}[3]{\lbrack\num{#1}\ {;}\ \num{#2}\rbrack\,\si{#3}}
 \sisetup{range-phrase = \ ;\ ,
          range-units  = brackets,
          list-units   = brackets,
          list-separator = {,\ },
          list-final-separator = {\ e\ }}
\usepackage{listings}% needed by siunitex
\usepackage{mathpazo}% needed by siunitex
%\usepackage{helvet}% needed by siunitex
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{miller}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH} 
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref}

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
 \1 What was blah blaha and blah?
 \2[] blah blah \textrightarrow{} lorem ipsum etc.
 \end{outline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well if I remove the undefined `\blindtext` your MWE compiles fine. So try to make an example that actually shows your problem. The option warn will only turn errors in warnings but not print more symbols -- and you should either pass the option to the package directly or setup it *before* you actually load textcomp. It is to late behind the package.

Comment: I've made some changes to the MWE file and it's compiling correctly (I didn't have the outlines package installed in Win7). However the real file, _main.tex_ file is still showing a gazillion errors concerning the textcomp package and the `\textrightarrow{}` command.

Comment: Maybe I should post the entire list of packages and their options? I tried it on the MWE and guess what? Errors!

Comment: Move `\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}` up in your document

Comment: Please check the 2nd not-so-MWE above: it's giving errors just like the original _main.tex_ file.

Comment: You really need more practice with MWEs. This one is missing `\begin{document}`. And it isn't loading textcomp. Put `\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}` directly behind the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: Note that the warning that you quote is about a _font_ encoding so unrelated to inputenc which is about the encoding used in the source file.

Comment: **@UlrikeFischer** I corrected the 2nd MWE, just a copy/paste issue. So I put `\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}` right after `\documentclass` and keep `\usepackage{inputenc}` after that? **@DavidCarlisle** So what should I do to have `\textrightarrow` AND compile the file? Do I load another package? This same file works fine on Kile/Debian, why is it giving trouble on TeXMaker/Win7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\textrightarrow
\end{document}
```

It generates the error:

```
! Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textrightarrow not provided by
(textcomp)                font family ppl in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead.
```

The problem is independent from package `inputenc`. The package mainly controls characters with character codes between 127 and 255, not the ASCII characters.
It maps them to LICRs (LaTeX internal character represnetation), e.g. `ö` becomes `\"o`.

Package `fontenc` maps the LICRs to the font encoding slots or replacement code.

The font encoding `TS1` is a little special. There are many fonts that do not cover all characters in this encoding. Therefore package `textcomp` defines encoding subsets that do not define all slots for such fonts. Font `ppl` (Palatino) has subset 3. It is explained in the `.log` file:

```
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
```

The font project [TeX Gyre](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre) extends the free available URW fonts:

> TeX Gyre Pag­ella is based on URW Pal­la­dio L (from Palatino, de­signed by Her­mann Zapf in the 1940s).

The text fonts can be easily replaced by TeX Gyre Pagella with package `tgpagella`:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
```

Package `mathpazo` is kept for the math fonts, that still use Palatino.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\begin{document}
\textrightarrow $\rightarrow$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Here the text version comes from TeX Gyre Pagella, the math version from the default Computer Modern fonts.

---

Example for LuaTeX/XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
  \textrightarrow → $\rightarrow →$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result LuaTeX]

The text and math versions of TeX Gyre Pagella (Math) use a different shape for U+2192 (RIGHTWARDS ARROW).